# Recover files from broken sd card (no boot)

Tags: raspbian, boot, sd-card, linux, filesystem

Is there any chance to recover some files that are on a SD card which doesn't boot anymore? Seems the last power-cut affected some files on the card and the Raspberry Pi is not able to boot anymore.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First, why it doesn't boot? What do the lights show? Debug it with [this wiki](http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting)

The problem might be in the FAT partition, that can be easily recovered by reformating and put back the files (Using either your image or one downloaded from the web.)

If it's the Linux filesystem, loading it on a Linux (even a liveCD) and running `fsck` might be enough to recover it.

So attach the SD card, open a console and do `dmesg` to view the label of the last disk (example `sdb`) discovered, do `fdisk -l /dev/sdb` to see what partitions exist. The Linux one should be called Linux (example `sdb2`). finally do `fsck /dev/sdb2`  to scan and fix the filesystem.

If all fails, maybe the SD has gone bad, I would do a `dd if=/dev/sdb of=file.img` (of even better `dd_rescue /dev/sdb file.img` if you have `dd_rescue` installed) to backup the SD to a file and trying to recover things from there, by transforming the image on a device with `losetup --find --show file.img` work on it.

Comment: Thanks man, at least I was able to recover some of my code by fsck command.

Answer (score 6):

If the filesystem isn't corrupted badly, it's possible to mount it on another system and copy the files off.

On another Linux system, type `sudo mount -o ro /dev/mmcblk0p2 /mnt` into a terminal. This mounts the SD card (assuming it's at `mmcblk0`) read-only at `/mnt`.

From there you can browse into the directory structure with a file manager and copy any needed files.